# OrderBy Linq with US Dates

Tags: c#, linq

I want to show a descending list of items with dates, but I can't seem to get the orderby clause to do a double sort. To a normal American human, you want to sort by Years first, then Months then days. See code below as well.

> October 21st, 2012 = 10/21/2012
>
> December 3rd, 2012 = 12/03/2012
>
> Januaray 15th, 2013 = 01/15/2013

No matter how I sort it, I always get what I see below, I've tried changing the string formatter, but that doesn't seem to work right. I added some convert/parse methods to the clause, but that didn't help. I'm looking for a high performance solution as this is a mobile app working with very long lists. What is the fastest way to do this? Create a Custom Comparer? Is there a way to do a second orderby clause?

What I always end up seeing, why isn't 2013 after 2012?

> 01/15/2013
>
> 10/21/2013
>
> 12/03/2012

```
IEnumerable<Group<FeedItem>> sortedItems = 
    from feedItem in _localLists.CustomList
    group feedItem by feedItem.EventDate
    into c
    orderby 
        (DateTime.ParseExact(c.Key, "MM-dd-yyyy", 
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) ascending
    select new Group<FeedItem>(c.Key, c);
```

Comment: Why are the dates stored as strings in the first place?

Comment: 2nd order by: `ThenBy` is the method. In Query Syntax, put a comma then the next field to sort by, e.g. `... orderby a, b`.

Comment: In your format specifier to ParseExact you have dashes ( - ) and in your example data you have slashes ( / ). Could the problem be that ParseExact is failing because the format doesn't match?

Comment: Ignore my /'s in the example as I meant to just to express the issue that the years are out of order. I've tried it without the ParseExact as well with same result.

Answer (score 0):

I went back and changed the string to a DateTime, which is obviously a plus. The issue was display only. I was using a telerik control to group and filter and sort a list, the linq was not driving what I was seeing. The solution was incorrect settings on the UI.